# Can two random variables be independent in some basis and dependant in other?

Tags: random-variable, independence

If some random variables forming N dimensions are dependant on each other is it possible that in a different coordinate system they'd be independent? For example if (X, Y) are two dependent RVs is it possible that R and  $\theta$ in a polar equivalent be independant?

Comment: Random variables don’t have bases in the linear algebra sense. For your specific question, $X$ and $Y$ being independent doesn’t guarantee that $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent (except when $X$ and $Y$ are zero-mean normal with equal variances).

Comment: "Polar coordinates" are not a basis, anyway, at least not in the sense of linear algebra.  This observation, taken together with that of @Dilip, exposes some uncertainty concerning the meaning of this question.  Would you like to edit the post to clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Thank you.  Please allow me to point out an equivalent formulation of your question: if two random variables $(R,\Theta)$ are *independent,* is it possible for a one-to-one function $(X(R,\Theta),Y(R,\Theta))$ of them *not* to be independent?  What do you think?

Comment: You can go the other way around, i.e. from two independent variables create two dependent variables, using an invertible transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Only a hint:

Your question is ambiguous, it admits of different interpretations, as verified by the comments of users Dilip Sarwate and whuber. For the specific question about transformation to polar coordinates, try the following simulation experiment: Let $X,Y$ be independent uniformñy distributed variables on the range $[-1,1]$. Simulate, transform to polar coordinates, and make the scatterplot of $R$ versus $\Theta$. Do they look independent?